# Why doesn't boost::enable_if cause an duplicate overloaded method compile error

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae

I have got the code for enable_if working and it is allowing me to do some awesome stuff but I thought it would cause an error as my two methods shown below have the same method signature.

Anyone know why this is allowed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits>


template<bool T, class R = void>
struct enable_if{
   typedef R type;
};

template<class R>
struct enable_if<false, R>{

};

template<class T>
typename enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>::value >::type  print(const T& item){
   std::cout << "T is a pod with the value: " << item << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
typename enable_if<!(boost::is_pod<T>::value) >::type  print(const T& item){
   std::cout << "T is not a pod with the value: " << item << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   print(1);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how does the compiler look at this I realise one typename enable_if<(boost::is_pod<T>::value) >::type and the other is typename enable_if<!(boost::is_pod<T>::value) >::type. When it does the initial look at methods they only vary by return type. Method overloading does not allow this. Does the compiler ignore this if a method is templated as it has not been instansiated yet?

Comment: This would be more visible if you edited your question. It would also allow better formatting. Remember to use backquotes ` for inline code segments. Like so `\`code\``.

Answer (score 5):

> my two methods shown below have the same method signature

Look closely:

```
… enable_if< boost …
```

vs

```
… enable_if< ! boost …
```

They're not the same, they're opposites. If one is disabled, the other is enabled. That guarantees that exactly one is always visible to the caller. (Remember, `enable_if` renders the declaration completely invisible if the condition is false.)

Comment: It does so when used inside templates (as intended) because you get SFINAE (Substitution failure is not an error). You can't use it like that outside templates - no substitution, so it is an error.

Comment: how does the compiler look at this I realise one typename enable_if<(boost::is_pod<T>::value) >::type and the other is typename enable_if<!(boost::is_pod<T>::value) >::type. When it does the initial look at methods they only vary by return type. Method overloading does not allow this. Does the compiler ignore this if a method is templated as it has not been instansiated yet?

Comment: @BlairDavidson both methods get instantiated. But `enable_if<false>::type` does not exist, and you get [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE). This renders the method invisible during overload resolution.

Comment: @BlairDavidson That's a good question, and I'll look for a quote from the standard later. Don't mark the answer as correct just yet. Long story short, function templates aren't functions and can have identical argument lists while overloading the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The two template functions **do** have the same signature as far as overload resolution goes.  If they both were instantiated for any requested type, there would be an error.

However, when the `enable_if` *succeeds for one and fails for the other*, rather than produce a compilation error due to substitution failure, **there is no error** (SFINAE: "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error"), and *the compiler simply ignores one of them as if it did not exist*.

Thus only one of the two templates is instantiated for the given type, and there is no overload resolution error.

Answer (score -1):

The two methods differ by return type, e.g., by the template specialization of enable_if.

Comment: -1 _"differ by return type"_, a method overload cannot differ only for return type...

Comment: @juanchopanza: actually it does, **if** it completely removes the method from being considered at all.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it is a bit philosophical, but in this case there is no return type. But I get your point.